# Can I create account with eos js?

Tags: accounts, mainnet, testnet

Is there a way to create an account via eos js

For example I would to avoid having to go to http://monitor.jungletestnet.io/#account to create an account on the testnet, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can view the related EOS-JS documentation at the following link: https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs/blob/e53c0e0bf791c22818ee3c9ea3592bcf1c0877ec/docs/2.-Transaction-Examples.md#create-new-account-multiple-actions

---

#### Create New Account (multiple actions)

```
const result = await api.transact({
  actions: [{
    account: 'eosio',
    name: 'newaccount',
    authorization: [{
      actor: 'useraaaaaaaa',
      permission: 'active',
    }],
    data: {
      creator: 'useraaaaaaaa',
      name: 'mynewaccount',
      owner: {
        threshold: 1,
        keys: [{
          key: 'PUB_R1_6FPFZqw5ahYrR9jD96yDbbDNTdKtNqRbze6oTDLntrsANgQKZu',
          weight: 1
        }],
        accounts: [],
        waits: []
      },
      active: {
        threshold: 1,
        keys: [{
          key: 'PUB_R1_6FPFZqw5ahYrR9jD96yDbbDNTdKtNqRbze6oTDLntrsANgQKZu',
          weight: 1
        }],
        accounts: [],
        waits: []
      },
    },
  },
  {
    account: 'eosio',
    name: 'buyrambytes',
    authorization: [{
      actor: 'useraaaaaaaa',
      permission: 'active',
    }],
    data: {
      payer: 'useraaaaaaaa',
      receiver: 'mynewaccount',
      bytes: 8192,
    },
  },
  {
    account: 'eosio',
    name: 'delegatebw',
    authorization: [{
      actor: 'useraaaaaaaa',
      permission: 'active',
    }],
    data: {
      from: 'useraaaaaaaa',
      receiver: 'mynewaccount',
      stake_net_quantity: '1.0000 SYS',
      stake_cpu_quantity: '1.0000 SYS',
      transfer: false,
    }
  }]
}, {
  blocksBehind: 3,
  expireSeconds: 30,
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot for pointing that out to me! I also was able to find it in the official docs now: https://eosio.github.io/eosjs/guides/2.-Transaction-Examples.html

Comment: Yep, I made sure to link you the latest version you would find there. But for the future, in case those docs change or the link dies, I linked the github commit that showed the documentation at this time. Glad it helped out.